# JavaFX building a new event chain

Tags: java, javafx, mouseevent

I'm in the process of making a checkers game. The 3 main components are a Board class, BoardPiece, and GamePiece. All GamePiece objects are essecetially invisible to the mouse. When a board piece is clicked, a check is performed to see if there is currently a GamePiece on the BoardPiece. So once a BoardPiece is clicked and a piece is found, the piece then needs to handle the event (for drag and drop). Below is an excerpt from the BoardPiece class:

```
setOnMousePressed(e -> {
    if (e.getTarget() instanceof BoardPiece) {
        BoardPiece bp = (BoardPiece)e.getTarget();
        GamePiece p = bp.getPiece();
        if (p != null) {
            p.fireEvent(e);
        }
    }
});
setOnMouseDragged(e -> {
    if (e.getTarget() instanceof BoardPiece) {
        BoardPiece bp = (BoardPiece)e.getTarget();
        GamePiece p = bp.getPiece();
        if (p != null) {
            p.fireEvent(e);
        }
    }
});
setOnMouseReleased(e -> {
    if (e.getTarget() instanceof BoardPiece) {
        BoardPiece bp = (BoardPiece)e.getTarget();
        GamePiece p = bp.getPiece();
        if (p != null) {
            p.fireEvent(e);
        }
    }
});
```

As you see, I have to manually tell the piece to handle each event, rather than the entire chain of events. I relatively new to JavaFX, and Java in general, so I'm primarily concerned with learning the most efficient way of doing things.

Answer (score 0):

You will have to setup all the event handlers separately, but as each of these handler have the same functionality you can simplify:

```
EventHandler<? super MouseEvent> mouseEventHanlder = e -> {
    if (e.getTarget() instanceof BoardPiece) {
        BoardPiece bp = (BoardPiece)e.getTarget();
        GamePiece p = bp.getPiece();
        if (p != null) {
            p.fireEvent(e);
        }
    }
};
setOnMousePressed(mouseEventHanlder);
setOnMouseDragged(mouseEventHanlder);
setOnMouseReleased(mouseEventHanlder);
```

Comment: Thanks! That's basically what I ended up doing, expect I just wrote the block into a function that was called inside the handler before I did anything else with the BoardPiece.